# How to stream a PDF

Tags: go, stream

I use Go and Gin for handle my web service. I want to stream a PDF file.
I tried to use html embed tag and pdf url for tag src, but this method not help me, because browser download the pdf.
For pdf handler I set content-type and someother headers but not work.

GO

```
func DownloadPdf(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-type", "application/pdf")
    c.FileAttachment(fmt.Sprintf("%s/order_%v.pdf", fileBasePath, myOrderUrl.OrderId), "bilit_pdf.pdf")
}
func LoadHtml(c *gin.Context) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("Modules/Pdf/templates/pdf.gohtml")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    if err = t.Execute(buf,  "http://localhost:3001/v2/pdf/download/YfTgLuPPDc"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if _,err:=buf.WriteTo(c.Writer);err!=nil{
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

HTLM

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%;width: 100%">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%;width: 100%;margin: 0;overflow:hidden">
<embed
        src="{{.}}"
        type="application/pdf"
        frameBorder="0"
        height="100%"
        width="100%">
</embed>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "streaming a PDF"?  A PDF is not a streaming format.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer with adding

```
c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-type", "application/octet-stream")
```

into my download code .
and opened PDF file when DownloadPdf route called .